# Замена BBCode URL регулярным выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, bbcode

Есть такое регулярное выражение:

```
/\[url=(.*)\](.*)\[\/url\]/Usi
```

И замена по нему:

```
<a href="$1" target="_blank">$2</a>
```

Текст вида

```
[url=http://google.ru]Сайт гугл[/url]
```

будет обработан нормально, а как сделать, чтобы если вдруг в $2 пустое значение, то подставить $1

```
[url=http://google.ru][/url]
```

Отобразилось как:

```
<a href="http://google.ru" target="_blank">http://google.ru</a>
```

Возможно ли это сделать при помощи **preg_replace**, а то я сделал через **preg_replace_callback** на время:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('/\[url=(.*)\](.*)\[\/url\]/Usi', function($match) {
                return '<a href="'.$match[1].'" target="_blank">'.(empty($match[2]) ? $match[1] : $match[2]).'</a>';
            }, $text);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно можно.
Вот только сложность увеличится на порядок.
Я бы лично воспользовался `preg_replace_callback`, но раз у Вас суеверный страх перед ним, то вот решение с помощью `preg_replace`:

```
$text= <<<HERETEXT
[url=http://google.ru]Сайт гугл[/url]
[url=http://google.ru][/url]
HERETEXT;

$re = <<<HEREREGEX
\[url=
(?(?=[^\]]*\]\[\/url\]) # если где-то справа пустой текст
    ([^\]]*)\]\[\/url\] | # ТО помещаем в первую группу адрес
    ([^\]]*)\](.*?)\[\/url\]       # ИНАЧЕ во вторую адрес, в третью текст
)

HEREREGEX;

echo preg_replace( "/$re/sux", '<a href="$1$2" target="_blank">$1$3</a>', $text );
```

[Живой пример](http://ideone.com/wG6a5u)